# Poor opentype font quality when printing xelatex generated PDF

Tags: xetex, pdf, color, opentype

I've been trying to print a PDF created with Xelatex, and the text (using opentype) is not as crystal clear as the same text printed directly from word (the edges are jagged/grainy).

Any suggestions?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/5764) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/5764) that illustrates your problem. Also include a screen shot of the zoomed PDF you created with XeLaTeX (remove the preceding `!`, and someone with editing privileges will re-insert it).

Comment: Also give the name of the pdf viewer you are using and maybe try some other too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nailed the program down to xcolor package. When using xcolor to define colors and using CMYK as the color space, black defined as:

```
\definecolor{blacktext}{HTML}{000000} % Main document font color, black
```

Doesn't come out as true black, and fonts become thinner as result. But changing the xcolor settings to:

```
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,rgb]{xcolor}
```

Makes the problem dissapear. This was tested in Windows using texlive, Adobe Acrobat Reader and Foxit, and a HP Laserjet printer (the problem is not the printer, you can see the difference in the PDF viewer directly).

Comment: A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they're marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (`{}`).